# Debugging in Python, mixed outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am required to handle user input so that the user only inputs 4 unique numbers, separated by a space, otherwise, an error message is shown. I was able to figure out how to do so, but am facing a particular problem. As you can see in the screenshot, the first time my input is 1 2 3 4, I get an expected output, then I input 1 1 1 1 and get an expected output again, but then, I again input 1 2 3 4, this is when I get an unexpected outcome. wondering if you can help me debug this code. Thank you.

The code can also be found here: https://pastebin.com/mMucpBPd

I have included a few print commands just to see where the problem is and what lst is at each step.

```
import random
def user_guess_validation():
    guess = input('Enter your guess. Numbers seperated by a space: ')
    x = guess.split() #splitting input and creating a list

    if len(x) == 4: # making sure input lenght is 4
        lst = []
        for each in x:
            if each.isdigit() == True and int(each) in range(1,10): #checking if item in list is actually a number between 1 and 9 
                lst.append(int(each))
                print('1, the lst here is', lst)
                continue
            else:
                print("1 Sorry, that's an invalid entry. Your guess must be 4 UNIQUE digits seperated by space.")
                user_guess_validation()
        for i in range(4): # checking if each input is unique

            for j in range(i+1,4):
                print('2, the lst here is', lst)
                if lst[i] == lst[j]:
                    print('index of i and j is: ',lst[i],lst[j])
                    print("2 Sorry, that's an invalid entry. Your guess must be 4 UNIQUE digits seperated by space.")

                    user_guess_validation()
        print('3, the lst here is', lst)
    else:
        print("3 Sorry, that's an invalid entry. Your guess must be 4 UNIQUE digits seperated by space.")
        user_guess_validation()


def main():
    secret_code = random.sample(range(1,10),4)
    print(secret_code)
    validated_guess = user_guess_validation()
    print(validated_guess)


    if validated_guess == secret_code:
        print('Correct!')
    else:
        print('Wrong! Try again.')
        user_guess_validation()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is written now, you're invoking the `user_guess_validation` function recursively to have the user enter new input if they enter something invalid. This is a BIG no-no. Your `main` function also could use a loop. If the user has valid input, but it doesn't match the secret code, you'll want to keep asking them to try again, not just ask them once.

```
def user_guess_validation():
    message = "Enter your guess: "
    while True:
        user_input = input(message)
        message = "Input invalid. Try again: "
        numbers = user_input.split()
        if len(set(numbers)) != 4:
            continue
        all_digits = True
        all_in_range = True
        for number in numbers:
            if not number.isdigit():
                all_digits = False
                break
            elif int(number) not in range(1, 10):
                all_in_range = False
                break

        if not all_digits or not all_in_range:
            continue
        return list(map(int, numbers))

def main():
    from random import sample

    secret_code = sample(range(1, 10), k=4)

    while True:
        validated_guess = user_guess_validation()

        if validated_guess == secret_code:
            print("Correct!")
            break
        print("Wrong! Try again.")

main()
```

Comment: I haven't learned try and except yet, is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: Sure. I've updated my post and used if-statements instead.

Comment: haven't learned map or any yet either lol. Additionally, how would I print 'error' and then ask for the guess numbers again if the user input is an invalid entry. Like 1111 or 1 1 1 1